# iOS Unwind Segue 'goBack' to perform a restart game

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uianimation

This is my storyboard where i hava a **HomeViewController** where i will start my game when i click "A". After finish i will go to 
**HalloffameViewController**
, and from there i would like to restart a game so i will directly to **GameViewController**. If I make a push action directly to gameViewController (since that are two navigation controller it will occur an error: `ios unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for` for that reason i believe that using rewind could be a good approach, and it almost works:

[image: ios]

I would like to perform a "restart" game. For that i would like to unwind to **GameViewController**. When i unwind from **HallOfFameViewController** it will perform a "back" to game showing all information that i left when i finished my game.To give me new information i will force to run `[self viewdidload]` like it was the first time.

This works but it looks like is not working 100% since will only perform viewdidload and not others implicit methods(viewwillappear,wiewdidappear,etc) that usually occurs when i load a new viewcontroller.

In fact i have one animation that is not working at all. Why animations  wont work? In fact, when debbugging it will enter inside, but simply doesn't show nothing, i checked already coordinates and content and seems to be there but i can't see.

my unwind method on (GameViewController):

-(IBAction)restartGame:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue{

```
[self viewDidLoad];
```

}

this works fine, but it seems that this wont reset the view controller. There are some way to do this?

Comment: What if you unwind to the home controller and have your `restartGame:` method there act as if the user had tapped the "A" button?

Comment: it will show "Home" and i want to show directly "Game".

Comment: As you've sort of figured out, `viewDidLoad` is only supposed to be called by iOS, not the app.  If you don't **really** want to reload the controller, your best bet is to restore everything to its starting state instead of calling `[self viewDidLoad];`.

Comment: thanks Philip but how can i do that "restore everything to its starting state"? poprootviewcontroller and call navigationcontroller on second object?

Comment: I can't tell you exactly but you must have a data model that your game controller uses to show game progress someplace.  Presumably, if you clear that back to the way it was when you first displayed the game, your controller has a fresh game context to work with.  Making the game state a separate object that the controller uses would be a good idea.  Then you could restart just by passing the controller a new state.